# how to auto-focus and auto-capture picture(Driver's License) with camera in android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, autosave, autofocus

[image: KeyRing app]
<sub>(source: [idownloadblog.com](http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Key-Ring-Reward-Cards-6.0-for-iOS-iPhone-screenshot-002.jpg))</sub>

I am developing an android app in which when i open camera intent, i would want something like this screen-shot from the app Keyring. Instead of the Bar Code, I want to capture a Drivers License. A border for the user to focus the card in, Auto-focus the image and Auto-Capture. Please give me direction! Any help will be appreciated.
Instead of Drivers License, i mistakenly put Credit Card earlier, sorry for the confusion.
Also, Can this be done with Action_Image_Capture Intent or do i have to open Camera object and create a preview and all?

Comment: The basics of this, CameraPreview on a SurfaceView, Camera with params set to auto focus, and taking a picture is discussed here http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html But yes it can be done. I did something similar to it recently building a text reading system.

Answer (score 2):

Use [card.io](https://www.card.io/). It's an open library that you can implement into yoour app which will accomplish exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry i had to change my question a bit. I am trying to save Driver's License picture and would later on use a [service](http://www.idscango.com/) which would extract the information and provide it to me. My apologies if i broke a stackoverflow rule. New to this :(